# How to run fans out of phase?

Tags: pwm, fan

I am working with server fans. The noise generated by these fans is quite disruptive, and I've read that running them 180 degrees out of phase could potentially reduce the noise.

I'm looking for practical guidance on this. These fans have PWM and tach.

Any insights, experiences, or technical details would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what "running fans out of phase" would even mean, let alone why that would reduce noise.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Consider 'smoothing" the airflow.

Answer (score 3):

The majority of the noise generated by these fans comes from turbulent airflow, which does not change if you synchronize the motors.

Doing so would reduce the noise generated by interference of motor noises, and it's being done in use cases where this makes an actual difference, for example on twin engine planes, the motors can be locked together because if the motors run with a small rpm difference, the motor noise seems to change all the time. Even there, the interlock does not use any specific phase angle.

An interlock at a specific phase angle would be useful only if the fans are not properly balanced and the fans are running at a resonance frequency of the case, and both of these should be remedied before building a workaround.

For server fans, the assumptions are

- the airflow is the source of the noise, not the motor itself
- there will be more than two fans per chassis
- the server will be mounted in a datacenter, and humans only go near it if they have to.

With these assumptions, the interface has been designed to be easy to implement and allow mixing of fans of different sizes in the same chassis, so server fans do not support phase control.